# I'm getting constant errors whenever I use sudo apt-get upgade, I'm currently running Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, upgrade

```
Err:1 http://mirror.lnx-solutions.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 base-files amd64 10.1ubuntu2.11
  404  Not Found [IP: 41.76.131.62 80]
Err:2 http://mirror.lnx-solutions.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 gzip amd64 1.6-5ubuntu1.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 41.76.131.62 80]
Ign:3 http://mirror.lnx-solutions.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 liblz4-1 i386 0.0~r131-2ubuntu3.1
```

Comment: They seem be be some unusual paths for upgrades. Hence the 404 error?

Comment: This is what I keep getting for every package throughout the terminal.

Comment: I am not getting a 404 error when opening `41.76.131.62/`

Comment: Remove the erroneous lines from your list of sources.

Answer (score 0):

Each of those URLs can be opened in a browser.

If you open the URL for gzip (http://mirror.lnx-solutions.com/ubuntu/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gzip/), you will find that --as of this writing-- that particular package version is indeed missing from that mirror.

That's why you are getting a 404 message. The file really is missing.

Solution: If this problem persists for more than day or so, then switch to a different mirror.

- It's not unusual for a mirror to drop out of sync for a day or two. Mirrors are big and those mirrors sites are contributed by volunteers (thank you, mirror hosts!)